# Converting some assembly to VB.NET - SHR operator working differently?

Tags: vb.net, assembly, bit-shift, disassembly

Well, a simple question here

I am studying some assembly, and converting some assembly routines back to VB.NET

Now, There is a specific line of code I am having trouble with, in assembly, assume the following:

```
EBX = F0D04080
```

Then the following line gets executed

```
SHR EBX, 4
```

Which gives me the following:

```
EBX = 0F0D0408
```

Now, in VB.NET, i do the following

```
variable = variable >> 4
```

Which SHOULD give me the same... But it differs a SLIGHT bit, instead of the value 0F0D0408 I get FF0D0408

So what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of the [>> operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dezyht83.aspx):

> In an arithmetic right shift, the bits shifted beyond the rightmost bit position are discarded, and the leftmost (sign) bit is propagated into the bit positions vacated at the left. This means that if pattern has a negative value, the vacated positions are set to one; otherwise they are set to zero.

If you are using a signed data type, `F0B04080` has a negative sign (bit `1` at the start), which is copied to the vacated positions on the left.

This is not something specific to VB.NET, by the way: `variable >> 4` is translated to the [IL instruction `shr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.shr.aspx), which is an "arithmetic shift" and preserves the sign, in contrast to the x86 assembly instruction `SHR`, which is an unsigned shift. To do an arithmetic shift in x86 assembler, `SAR` can be used.

To use an unsigned shift in VB.NET, you need to use an unsigned variable:

```
Dim variable As UInteger = &HF0D04080UI
```

The [`UI` type character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s9cz43ek.aspx) at the end of `F0D04080` tells VB.NET that the literal is an unsigned integer (otherwise, it would be interpreted as a negative signed integer and the assignment would result in a compile-time error).

Comment: Spot on - I had misread the question and tried shifting 0F0D0408 :)

Comment: Alright but how do i fix this to give me the same output in VB.NET as it does in assembly?

thanks

Comment: @zeta: You need to use an unsigned variable. I've extended my answer.

Comment: works like a charm, just didn't know i had to add the UI, explains why i kept getting the errors when trying to make it unsigned

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

VB's `>>` operator does an arithmetic shift, which shifts in the sign bit rather than 0's.

```
variable = (variable >> shift_amt) And Not (Integer.MinValue >> (shift_amt - 1))
```

should give you an equivalent value, even if it is a bit long.  Alternatively, you could use an unsigned integer (UInteger or UInt32), as there's no sign bit to shift.